# Arquillian REST Testing Could not lookup value for field public java.net.URL

Tags: java, rest, testing, jboss-arquillian

I am trying to test our REST Webservices with Arquillian.

I am new on Arquillian and I've never do testing before, i did a small tutorial and read the documentation and some other stuff and finally tried to write a simple test for my REST methode. But i am getting an exception saying:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not lookup value for field public java.net.URL ma.campus.services.ws.UtilisateurRestTest.deploymentURL
```

My Test Class:

```
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.RunAsClient;
import org.jboss.arquillian.core.api.annotation.Inject;
import org.jboss.arquillian.extension.rest.client.ArquillianResteasyResource;
import org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.arquillian.test.api.ArquillianResource;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.WebArchive;
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import ma.campus.entities.Utilisateur;
import ma.campus.services.UtilisateurService;
import ma.campus.services.ws.dto.UtilisateurDto;

@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class UtilisateurRestTest {

@ArquillianResource
public URL deploymentURL;

@Deployment(testable = false)
public static WebArchive create() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class).
                addClasses(Utilisateur.class,UtilisateurService.class,UtilisateurRest.class,UtilisateurDto.class);
}

@Inject
UtilisateurRest utilisateurRest;

@Test
@RunAsClient
@GET @Path("/utilisateur")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON) 
    public void listAllUtilisateurs(@ArquillianResteasyResource UtilisateurRest utilisateurRest) throws Exception{

    if(utilisateurRest!=null)
    {
        System.out.println("Not Null");
    ResponseEntity<List<UtilisateurDto>> response=utilisateurRest.listAllUtilisateurs();

   Assert.assertNotNull(response);

   Assert.assertNotEquals(new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT),response);

   final List<Utilisateur> result = (List<Utilisateur>)response;

   Assert.assertNotNull(result);
   Assert.assertEquals(1, result.size());
    }else
        System.out.println("Null");     
}           
}
```

My pom.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>ma.campus</groupId>
<artifactId>GestionDeParking</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<name>GestionDeParking</name>
<description></description>

<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
    <!-- <version>1.4.5.RELEASE</version> -->
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
            <scope>import</scope>
            <type>pom</type>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-solr</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-core</artifactId>
        <version>1.13</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.scala-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>scala-library</artifactId>
        <version>2.11.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <!-- test -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-javaee-7.0</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.3.Final</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.0.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-weld-ee-embedded-1.1</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.CR9</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.weld</groupId>
        <artifactId>weld-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.Final</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.4</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <!-- for rest testing -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-rest-client-impl-jersey</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Alpha3</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
        <artifactId>arquillian-rest-client-impl-3x</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Alpha3</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.resteasy</groupId>
        <artifactId>resteasy-jackson-provider</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.1.GA</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <forkMode>perTest</forkMode>
                <skip>false</skip>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

My REST Service:

```
@RestController
public class UtilisateurRest {
    public static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(UtilisateurRest.class);
@Autowired
private UtilisateurService utilisateurService;

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoderService passwordEncoderService;

// ------------------- All Users---------------------------------
@Secured(value={"ROLE_1"})
@RequestMapping(value = "/utilisateur", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<List<UtilisateurDto>> listAllUtilisateurs() {
    List<Utilisateur> listUtilisateur = utilisateurService.findAllUtilisateurs();

List<UtilisateurDto> listUtilisateurDto = new ArrayList<>(listUtilisateur.size());


    for (Utilisateur utilisateur : listUtilisateur) {
        listUtilisateurDto.add(utilisateur.convertToUtilisateurDto());

    }

    System.out.println("********** listUtilisateurDto == "+listUtilisateurDto.size());

    if (listUtilisateurDto.isEmpty()) {
        return new ResponseEntity(HttpStatus.NO_CONTENT);
    }
    return new ResponseEntity<List<UtilisateurDto>>(listUtilisateurDto, HttpStatus.OK);
}
}
```

Full stacktrace:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Could not lookup value for field public java.net.URL ma.campus.services.ws.UtilisateurRestTest.deploymentURL
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.enricher.resource.ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.enrich(ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.java:68)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestInstanceEnricher.enrich(TestInstanceEnricher.java:51)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.ClientTestInstanceEnricher.enrich(ClientTestInstanceEnricher.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:128)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createBeforeContext(ContainerEventController.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.before(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:98)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$4.evaluate(Arquillian.java:216)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:384)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$5.evaluate(Arquillian.java:231)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7$1.invoke(Arquillian.java:295)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.execute(ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.on(ClientBeforeAfterLifecycleEventExecuter.java:66)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:103)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createContext(ContainerEventController.java:128)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.client.ContainerEventController.createBeforeContext(ContainerEventController.java:114)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:116)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:83)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:86)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:95)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:133)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:105)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.fireCustomLifecycle(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:142)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$7.evaluate(Arquillian.java:289)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$2.evaluate(Arquillian.java:182)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.multiExecute(Arquillian.java:384)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.access$200(Arquillian.java:54)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian$3.evaluate(Arquillian.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.junit.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:678)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: All Providers for type class java.net.URL returned a null value: [org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.enricher.resource.URLResourceProvider@4a194c39]
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.enricher.resource.ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.lookup(ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.java:126)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.enricher.resource.ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.enrich(ArquillianResourceTestEnricher.java:66)
    ... 108 more
```